# Why CAN I use aliases in the WHERE clause? (Oracle XE 11g)

Tags: sql, oracle11g, alias, where-clause

While studying for the 1Z0-051 exam, I've read in many places that column aliases **cannot** be used in the `WHERE` clause.
However, when I submit the following query:

```
SELECT e.first_name, d.department_name
FROM employees e, departments d
WHERE e.department_id = d.department_id
AND e.first_name LIKE 'B%';
```

I get the following results:

```
FIRST_NAME              DEPARTMENT_NAME
---------------------   -----------------------
Bruce                   IT
Britney                 Shipping
```

Can someone explain why these aliases **are** working? Even better, what's the overall rule/concept I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use **column** name aliases in a `where` clause, but **table** name aliases which you do.